# Is it equation true - limit

Tags: analysis, limits

Is it true that :
$\lim_{ x\to\infty }  \left( 1+\frac{f \left( x \right) }{x} \right) ^x = \exp \left(  \lim_{ x\to\infty } f \left( x \right)   \right)$ ?

Assumption is that limit of $\lim_{ x\to\infty } f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Yes. Proof: what can you say about $\log(1+f(x)/x)$ when $x\to\infty$?

Comment: I was wondering who was that sad man who downvoted both answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{f(x)}x\right)^x
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp \left(x\log \left(1+\frac{f(x)}x \right) \right)=\exp \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log \left(1+\frac{f(x)}x\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&=&\exp \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x \left(\frac{f(x)}x+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\right)
=\exp \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&=&\exp \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\right).
\end{eqnarray}

The limit exchange in the second equality is justified by the fact that the exponential is continuous and that the expression inside converges.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This is essentially correct, but I guess some people don't like seeing the second equality before seeing a proof of the convergence of the expression inside.

Comment: Could be. Actually, it's probably much better to address the limit inside first. What I don't like is when people downvote without saying why.

Comment: Can't help it. People aren't obligated to explain their upvotes or downvotes. In this case, the person downvoting probably lost an opportunity to learn something from your answer.

Comment: One more possible reason for the downvote: You haven't mentioned that $\frac{f(x)}{x} \to 0$, in order to justify the third equality.

Answer (score 1):

Since there exist $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=l$ we have that $f$ is bounded in the neighborhood of $\infty$. So $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ and we can write
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^x=
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{f(x)}}\right)^{f(x)}=
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{f(x)}}\right)^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)}=
e^l
$$

Comment: Is the second limit in second equality justified by the fact that (1+f(x)/x)^(x/f(x)) converges ?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but perhaps this was downvoted because you don't deal with the case: $f(x) = 0$ infinitely often?